# CSS Slider - Hover functionality rather than click

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a css slider (code attached). It's working fine when buttons are clicked, however, I would prefer to get each banner to slide when the buttons are hovered on.

I tried to combine the :hover and :target events but didn't have any luck.

If anyone knows of a way to get the sliding functionality on hover then that would be great.

Thanks for any help. I would like to achieve this with CSS only, if possible.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-holder {
  width: 600px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-holder {
  width: 3000px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 280px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: left 2s;
  -moz-transition: left 2s;
  -o-transition: left 2s;
  transition: left 2s;
}

.slider-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

#slider-image-0:target~.image-holder {
  left: 0px;
}

#slider-image-1:target~.image-holder {
  left: -600px;
}

#slider-image-2:target~.image-holder {
  left: -1200px;
}

#slider-image-3:target~.image-holder {
  left: -1800px;
}

#slider-image-4:target~.image-holder {
  left: -2400px;
}

.button-holder>a>img {
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-holder">
  <span id="slider-image-0"></span>
  <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
  <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
  <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
  <span id="slider-image-4"></span>
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280" class="slider-image" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button-holder">
  <a href="#slider-image-1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: when it moves you won't be able to hover over it anymore and it'll go right back.

Comment: You can't do this on hover with CSS alone, because as soon as you mouse off any of the sliders it's going to move back to the default position (since it no longer matches a :hover rule). You'll need JavaScript.

Comment: @skyline3000 with some CSS magic we can ;) using big value for transitions we can lock the state on hover even if we remove the hover

Comment: @andrewgi it's possible with some CSS tricks :)

Comment: That's a very interesting approach but I wouldn't say it's a practical solution. The image still starts to go back to the default state when not hovering a slider notch, and if you move your mouse over the notches quickly the transitions do not finish and stop at in-between states which is not desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use some transition hacks but you have to change the html structure to be able to use sibling selector.

Here is an idea where I used flexbox in order to keep the same structure visually:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
 display:flex;
 width:600px;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

.slider-holder {
  order:-1;
  width: 600px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-holder {
  width: 3000px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 280px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 7000s; /*Use a big value to block the image change*/
  left: 0;
}

.slider-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

a[href="#slider-image-0"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: 0.5px; /*Yes it's not 0px here, we need something different from the initial state to be able to trigger the transition (Yes I know it's not intuitive ..)*/
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-1"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -600px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-2"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -1200px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-3"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -1800px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-4"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -2400px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.button-holder>a>img {
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="#slider-image-0"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
<a href="#slider-image-1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
<a href="#slider-image-2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
<a href="#slider-image-3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
<a href="#slider-image-4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
<div class="slider-holder">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/ff0000" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/00ff00" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/f0f0f0" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/0000ff" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280" class="slider-image" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```