# CSS - Alternative to using (~) sibling operator

Tags: html, css

I have a slider that works perfect with my HTML and CSS code, however, when I want to import into my email management package it won't allow the use of tildas.

I was just wondering, based on the code below, if there's an alternative to targeting the code through CSS rather than the use of the CSS sibling operator so I can test if the new adjusted code can be imported to the platform.

Thanks for any help. Code below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.slider-holder {
  order: -1;
  width: 600px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-holder {
  width: 3000px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 280px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 7000s;
  /*Use a big value to block the image change*/
  left: 0;
}

.slider-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

a[href="#slider-image-0"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: 0.5px;
  /*Yes it's not 0px here, we need something different from the initial state to be able to trigger the transition (Yes I know it's not intuitive ..)*/
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-1"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -600px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-2"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -1200px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-3"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -1800px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-4"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -2400px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.button-holder>a>img {
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#slider-image-0"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <div class="slider-holder">
    <div class="image-holder">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/ff0000" class="slider-image" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/00ff00" class="slider-image" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/f0f0f0" class="slider-image" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/0000ff" class="slider-image" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280" class="slider-image" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I remember this code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526098/css-slider-hover-functionality-rather-than-click/52526402#52526402 .. if you find the answer useful it's good to mark it as accepted before adding a new question ;) It seems you are not accepting any answers which means that all your issues aren't solved?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's not the same question, but yes, it seems that you answered his previous question. He should mark it as accepted.

Comment: @ItayGal I never said it's the same question ;) but using a provided answer to hightlight another issues means that the previous question was solved. So he need to mark as accepted to clear it from the unnaswred queue. He should do the same for each of his questions to avoid people wasting time adding more answer when he already have what he want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the operator `+` which takes the next element. Note that for it to work you'll have to chain multiple elements to get to the slider

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.slider-holder {
  order: -1;
  width: 600px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-holder {
  width: 3000px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 280px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 7000s;
  /*Use a big value to block the image change*/
  left: 0;
}

.slider-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

a[href="#slider-image-0"]:hover + .slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: 0.5px;
  /*Yes it's not 0px here, we need something different from the initial state to be able to trigger the transition (Yes I know it's not intuitive ..)*/
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-1"]:hover + a + a + a + .slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -600px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-2"]:hover + a + a +.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -1200px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-3"]:hover + a + .slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -1800px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-4"]:hover + .slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -2400px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.button-holder>a>img {
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#slider-image-0"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
  <div class="slider-holder">
    <div class="image-holder">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/ff0000" class="slider-image" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/00ff00" class="slider-image" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/f0f0f0" class="slider-image" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/0000ff" class="slider-image" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280" class="slider-image" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```